# Does the BitTorrent protocol allow you to share empty directories?

Tags: bittorrent

When I tried to create a torrent file out of a directory that contains several empty child directories, they were ignored and omitted in the torrent file. I wonder if this is a *qBittorrent* thing or a limitation of the *BitTorrent* protocol. Does the BitTorrent protocol allow you to share empty directories, preserving the actual file tree?

[image: An image of a directory that contains several empty child directories.]
[image: An image of such directories having been ignored and omitted in the torrent file.]

---

## Edit ⸺ There’s torrents that have empty directories out there.

Yes, there’s actually a few. But how?

[image: 19 of 53619 torrents have empty directories.]

[image: An empty directory in the torrent 05e4bb4227689c24fb61cd200e812d402526475b]

#### Opened with BEncode editor

[image: The last element of the list “path” is an empty string]

#### How qBittorrent handle these mysterious empty directories

[image: How qBittorrent handle empty directories]

Comment: Not an expert so not sure but I think the isn't such limitation.

Comment: @ChanganAuto You mean it is possible to create a torrent file for sharing empty directories, right? Thank you for your opinion. What made you think so?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've seen many torrents with empty directories inside. Namely old DVD rips that usually have the "audio" folder empty, other with "software" trees including one or more empty directories, among many other examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to share empty directories in the BitTorrent protocol.

All files in a BitTorrent metafile (.torrent file) are listed in the "files" list which is located inside the "info" dictionary. Directories are stored as part of the "path" to a a file relative to the root directory.

The BitTorrent v1 protocol specification states:

> path - A list of UTF-8 encoded strings corresponding to subdirectory
> names, the last of which is the actual file name (a zero length list
> is an error case).

See: https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html

This means that it is impossible to share directories without any files in them as the last element of a path will always be interpreted as a filename.

Following example shows how the paths to files are stored inside a .torrent file (formatted as JSON):

```
{
    "info": {
        "files": [
            {
                "length": 1647396,
                "path": [
                    "stage_2_detailed_class_info.csv"
                ]
            },
            {
                "length": 124100,
                "path": [
                    "stage_2_test_images_jpg",
                    "0000a175-0e68-4ca4-b1af-167204a7e0bc.jpg"
                ]
            },
        ],
        "name": "kaggle-pneumonia-jpg",
    }
}
```

This torrent contains two files:

- kaggle-pneumonia-jpg/stage_2_detailed_class_info.csv
- kaggle-pneumonia-jpg/stage_2_test_images_jpg/0000a175-0e68-4ca4-b1af-167204a7e0bc.jpg"

The directory "stage_2_test_images_jpg" only exists because it is contained in the "path" for the file "0000a175-0e68-4ca4-b1af-167204a7e0bc.jpg".

If we would remove "0000a175-0e68-4ca4-b1af-167204a7e0bc.jpg" from the torrent the directory "stage_2_test_images_jpg" would become the last element in the "path" and would become a file instead of a directory.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. I edited the question adding images of torrents I found having empty directories. Could you look into those mysterious torrents? Are those non-standard?

Comment: These directories look like they are empty because they only contain a single file with a size of 0 bytes. The AUDIO_TS folder show the empty '0' file and the qbittorrent image has an empty file named "_".

Comment: I opened one of them with the BEncode editor, and it says the list “path” has an empty string, which is an invalid filename, at the end.

Comment: You are right that it's not a zero, maybe it's actually a single space. That would fit with qBittorrent rendering that as an underscore.

Comment: Double-checked it with the BEncode editor and tried to copy & paste it. Apparently it’s a completely empty string, not a space, even. I think those are just not complying with the standard about empty directories being forbidden.